# Digit sum function in R

Tags: r

I was looking for the quite basic numeric function [digit sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) in R.

- I did not find a preinstalled function.
- Even in Stackoverflow's
  extensive R library I did not find a record.

Therefore tried myself ending with following function:

```
# Function to calculate a digit sum
digitsum = function (x) {sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split="")))) }
```

I works, but I still struggle with following two questions:

1. Is there really in plain R no function for digit sum?
2. Is there a smarter way to code this function?

Comment: Like DWin said, there's next to no use for this function other than in dusty corners of number theory.  You won't find a digit-product function either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should be better:

```
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, even I do not really understand how it works - it works just fine after few tests.

Comment: @user2030503, this typical algorithm would be written using `while` in other programming languages, whereas here we can take advantage of vectorization. I get every digit separately by dividing of some power of 10 and getting a remainder. Look at `x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))`, then add `floor`, `%% 10` to understand it better.

Comment: Nice solution.  I agree with Simon, very clever.

Answer (score 9):

I wondered which of the three suggested methods (plus a fourth one) is the fastest so I did some benchmarking.

1. `digitsum1 <- function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = ""))))`
2. `digitsum2 <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)`
3. Using function digitsBase from package GLDEX:

   ```
   library(GLDEX, quietly = TRUE)
   digitsum3 <-  function(x) sum(digitsBase(x, base = 10))
   ```
4. Based on a function by Greg Snow in the [R-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/270786.html):

   `digitsum4 <- function(x) sum(x %/% 10^seq(0, length.out = nchar(x)) %% 10)`

Benchmark code:

```
library(microbenchmark, quietly = TRUE)
# define check function
my_check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(values[[1]], x)))
}
x <- 1001L:2000L
microbenchmark(
  sapply(x, digitsum1),
  sapply(x, digitsum2),
  sapply(x, digitsum3),
  sapply(x, digitsum4),
  times = 100L, check = my_check
)
```

Benchmarks results:

```
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                  expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval
#>  sapply(x, digitsum1)  3.41  3.59  3.86   3.68  3.89  5.49   100
#>  sapply(x, digitsum2)  3.00  3.19  3.41   3.25  3.34  4.83   100
#>  sapply(x, digitsum3) 15.07 15.85 16.59  16.22 17.09 24.89   100
#>  sapply(x, digitsum4)  9.76 10.29 11.18  10.56 11.48 45.20   100
```

Variant 2 is slightly faster than variant 1 while variants 4 and 3 are much slower. Although the code of variant 4 seems to be similar to variant 2, variant 4 is less efficient (but still better than variant 3).

Full benchmark results (including graphs) are on [github](https://github.com/UweBlock/digitsum_benchmark/blob/master/digitsum_benchmark.md).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would think there would be an inbuilt function to do that. It not really a statistical operation. More of a number theory sort of procedure. (There are many examples that can be found with a search of the Rhelp Archives. I [formerly used] [Markmail](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list:org.r-project.r-help%20%22digit%20sum%22) for that purpose but there are other search engines like RSeek, GMane, and the Newcastle webpage. Now you could search the mail repository by doing a Google search at the canonical R-help repository: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstat.ethz.ch%2Fpipermail%2Fr-help%2F Your function would take a series of numbers and return a single number that was the digit sum of all of them. If that were the goal then it looks reasonably designed.  I would have guessed that one would want the digit sums from each number:

```
sapply( c(1,2,123), 
        function(x) sum( as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split=""))) ))
[1] 1 2 6
```

There is a "digitizing" funciton digitsBase in pkg:GLDEX, and you could replace your as.numeric(unlist(split(as.character(x),""))) with that function:

```
digitsBase(x, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, your hint for Markmail is very helpful. Was not aware of it.

Comment: Sadly MarkMail is no more.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last digit with `x %% 10L` and remove the last digit with `x %% 10L`. Doing this and summing up the last digit in a loop with `floor(log10(max(x)))` repetitions will give the result.

```
digitsum <- function(x) {
  r <- x %% 10L
  for(i in seq_len(floor(log10(max(x))))) {
    x <- x %/% 10L
    r <- r + x %% 10L
  }
  r
}
digitsum(c(1,2,123))
#[1] 1 2 6
```

The same in C++ using RCPP.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
Rcpp::IntegerVector sod(const Rcpp::IntegerVector& x) { //sum of digits
  IntegerVector r(no_init(x.size()));
  for(int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i) {
    int s = x[i];
    r[i] = s % 10;
    while(s > 9) {
      s /= 10;
      r[i] += s % 10;
    }
  }
  return r;
}")
sod(c(1,2,123))
#[1] 1 2 6
```

---

Benchmark (taken from @Uwe)

```
x <- 1001L:2000L
digitsum2 <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
bench::mark(sapply(x, digitsum2), digitsum(x), sod(x))
#  expression                min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc gc/se…¹ n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>           <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 sapply(x, digitsum2)   1.83ms   2.12ms      468.   31.67KB    18.1   207     8
#2 digitsum(x)           18.71µs  19.59µs    50810.   31.62KB    30.5  9994     6
#3 sod(x)                 6.12µs   6.37µs   155482.    6.45KB    15.5  9999     1
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do for finding the sum of digits in R :

```
x = readline("Enter the number")
a = as.integer(c(strsplit(x,split="")[[1]]))
print((sum(a)))
```