# Sum of digits in a numeric matrix per row

Tags: r, matrix, sum

Having a matrix like:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
   [1,]   11   14   17   20   23   26
   [2,]   12   15   18   21   24   27
   [3,]   13   16   19   22   25   28
```

I want to get only the rows that have sum of digits for each row between 2 
   values.

Sum of digits for each row:

```
   [1] 30
   [2] 38
   [3] 42
```

so if I want to get only rows where sum of digits is between `31` and `40`, then 
   only the row `2` with value `38` must be returned.

Comment: Related thread: [digit-sum-function-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675285/digit-sum-function-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
 i1 <-  apply(m1, 1, function(x) {
         v1 <- sum(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ""), as.numeric)))
         v1 > 31 & v1 < 40})

m1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   12   15   18   21   24   27
```

---

Or

```
i1 <- sapply(strsplit(do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(m1)), ""), 
               function(x) sum(as.integer(x)))
m1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
```

---

Or we can do

```
f1 <-  Vectorize(function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10))
i1 <-  rowSums(t(apply(m1, 1, f1))) %in% 31:40
m1[i1, , drop = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(11:28, nrow = 3)
```

Comment: It was when I saw your answer that I understood his question, nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
l <- strsplit(as.character(t(m)), "")
mx <- max(lengths(l))
res <- rowSums(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(l, 'length<-', mx))), 
              ncol = ncol(m)*mx, byrow = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
m[res>31 & res<42,]

#[1] 12 15 18 21 24 27
```

- `l` is the list of all digits in `m`
- `mx` is the maximum length of a number in `m` just in case the number of digits are not equal for all numbers within `m` (for your case it is `2`)
- Then you make all list elements of equal length (by adding `NA`) and getting a matrix out of list elements where `rowSums` gives you the sum of digits per row in `m`
- Once you have the row-sum of digits (i.e., `res`), you filter out those rows of interest.