# Large number digit sum

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that computes the sum of digits of large numbers, of the order of `100^100`. The approach described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18675285/1977587) does not work, as shown below. I tried to come up with a function that does the job, but have not been able to get very far.

The inputs would be of the form `a^b`, where `1 < a, b < 100` and `a` and `b` are integers. So, in that sense, I am open to making `digitSumLarge` a function that accepts two arguments.

```
digitSumLarge <- function(x) {
  pow <- floor(log10(x)) + 1L
  rem <- x
  i <- 1L
  num <- integer(length = pow)
  # Individually isolate each digit starting from the largest and store it in num
  while(rem > 0) {
    num[i] <- rem%/%(10^(pow - i))
    rem <- rem%%(10^(pow - i))
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  return(num)
}
# Function in the highest voted answer of the linked question.
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
```

Consider the following tests:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = ''))
# [1] 1.234568e+17
sum(x)
# 90
digitSumLarge(as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = '')))
# 85
digitsum(as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = '')))
# 81, with warning message about loss of accuracy
```

Is there any way I can write such a function in R?

Comment: Given that you're looking at exponents on the order of 100, does your requirement even really need to keep track of an exact mantissa?  In other words, would knowing the number to within a factor of 10 be sufficient for you?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your input is. Surely it is not a floating point number nor a vector of separate digits.

Comment: Yes, I would like the exact digit sum, unfortunately.

Comment: What’s wrong with `sum(x)`?

Comment: The input would be numbers of the form `a^b`, with `1 < a, b < 100`

Comment: You need a big integer library (or write your own, which isn't too hard if you are not too worried about efficiency).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need arbitrary precision numbers. `a^b` with R's numerics (double precision floats) can be only represented with limited precision and not exactly for sufficiently large input.

```
library(gmp)
a <- as.bigz(13)
b <- as.bigz(67)
sum(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(a^b), split = "")[[1]]))
#[1] 328
```