# Function for summing digits using R

Tags: r

I am working in RStudio and trying to develop a function that will sum the digits together for any integer values.

I am only able successfully develop the function for single and double digits, but when i start adding for example 12345 the function does not work.

can someone guide me on what I am missing?

My example code is below:

```
myfunction2 <- function(input) {
  if(input < 10) {
    return(input)
  } else {
      return(sum((input%%10) + floor(input/10)))
}
```

this function will return 6 if i input 33 and so on but when i increase the number of digits to 3 like 123 it breaks

Comment: You need a loop (or a recursive approach). Unless `floor(input/10)))` is a single digit, this approach won't work. Also, `floor(input/10)))` can be written as `input %/% 10`

Comment: There are existing answers for this question, but I don't know if you want to look at them, or if this question should be closed as duplicate, since you're trying to work something out from first principles. But if you want them: [here they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675285/digit-sum-function-in-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One loop-less option is to use cSplit from the splitstackshape package to separate your number into a vector with one element per character, then add up all the elements in the vector. This works for 1 (`single_num`) or `many` numbers.

```
library(splitstackshape)
single_num <- 17692
many <- c(12345, 678910, 222, 10, 7099998)

sums <- function(vec) {
   print(rowSums(cSplit(as.data.frame(vec),1, sep = '', stripWhite = FALSE), na.rm = T))
}

sums(single_num)
==> 25
sums(many)
==> 15 31 6 1 51
```

- install and load the splitstackshape package
- convert the value or vector given to a dataframe
- use the cSplit function on column 1 with an empty separator to create a column with a df for each character (colnames automatically added by cSplit)
- calculate the sum across each row and print

If you put in one number there'll be one row and one result, whereas if you put in a vector of multiple numbers there'll be that many rows and results.

`na.rm = T` is needed when you put in values with different numbers of characters, because otherwise the shorter ones will end up with NAs in the later columns and `rowSums()` will return NA.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

myfunction2 <- function(inp) {
  if (inp < 10) {
    return(inp)
    
  } else{
    input_str = toString(inp)
    input_split = str_split(input_str, '')[[1]]
    mysum = 0
    for(i in 1:length(input_split)){
      mysum = mysum + as.numeric(input_split[i])
    }
    return(mysum)
  }
}
```