# Sum of digits of the numbers in a vector

Tags: r

I need to find the sum of digits  of the numbers in a vector and I wrote this:

```
once1<- 10:19
sum<-0
for (i in 1:10){
  while(once1[i] > 0) {
    resto <- once1[i] %% 10
    sum[i] <- sum[i] + resto
    once1[i] <- once1[i] %/% 10
  }
i<-i+1
}
sum
```

But it only works for the first iteration and cannot see why.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you wanna check more functions that does that, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675285/digit-sum-function-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you didn't create `sum` as a vector. It will work with this addition:

```
once1<-10:19
once1
sum<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
for (i in 1:10){
  while(once1[i] > 0) {
    resto <- once1[i] %% 10
    sum[i] <- sum[i] + resto
    once1[i] <- once1[i] %/% 10
  }
  i<-i+1
}
sum
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative:

```
> sapply(strsplit(as.character(once1), ""), function(x){sum(as.numeric(x))})
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```