# vectorised function to calculate sum of digits

Tags: r, vector, sum, digits

I have a vector of numbers (eg. `c(1, 11, 1232, 4221, 2)`), and I need a corresponding vector of the sums of digit of each element (`c(1, 2, 8, 9, 2)`, in the previous example).

I found some nice solutions for single numbers. the nicest (from [Digit sum function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675285/digit-sum-function-in-r)) is:

```
digitsum <- function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
```

However, this solution is not vectorized. It would only work on one element at a time.

And so, **Is there a way to vectorize this solution, and create a similar function that would work on vectors?** (instead of looping through all elements, that is)

Comment: Just surround the function by `Vectorize()`, i.e. `digitsum <- Vectorize(function(x) sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10))`

Comment: It depends why you want to vectorise - vectorised versions of this will still be looping over the vector in some way, so you are unlikely to get an improvement in run time unless you use CPP, but you can either use the `apply` family (`sapply()` etc) or make use of R's base `Vectorize()` function (note the capital V) if you just want a tidier way to lay it out.

Comment: `nchar(x)` can (should) be replaced by `ceiling(log10(x + 0.1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> x=c(1, 11, 1232, 4221, 2)
> sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),""),function(y){sum(as.numeric(y))})
[1] 1 2 8 9 2
```

Comment: thanks! I'll slightly edit my question to be clearer

Comment: I just Wrapped a function() around your sapply() and it works. thanks

Comment: Don't coerce to characters.

Comment: @Roland why not?

Comment: Because you have numeric input and numeric output and coercion and string operations are inefficient compared to numeric operations.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility, inspired from [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/0ce09d1f0517e9f177d3?permalink_comment_id=2937394#gistcomment-2937394), which does not require splitting or converting to character:

```r
dsum <- function(n) ifelse(n < 10, n, n %% 10 + dsum(floor(n / 10)))
dsum(x)
#[1] 1 2 8 9 2
```

---

Benchmark (with a vector of size 100,000): this solution is the fastest.

```r
set.seed(1)
s <- sample(1e5)
dsum <- function(n) ifelse(n < 10, n, (n %% 10) + dsum(floor(n / 10)))
sap <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),""),function(y){sum(as.numeric(y))})
digitsum <- function(x) vapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "", TRUE), function(x) sum(as.integer(x)), 0L)
bench::mark(Maël = dsum(s), GKi = digitsum(s), user2974951 = sap(s))

#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t>
#1 Maël         40.9ms  48.6ms   15.3  38.94MB   17.2      8     9   522ms
#2 GKi         320.6ms   331ms    3.02  1.91MB    3.02     2     2   662ms
#3 user2974951 326.1ms 340.3ms    2.94  4.82MB    2.94     2     2   681ms
```

Comment: Just wrote this solution only to come and find it here haha. I used `n%%10 + fn(n%/%10)` though

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping over all elements you can loop over the maximum number of digits `1 + floor(log10(max(x)))` and get the last digit with `x %% 10L` and remove the last digit with `x %% 10L`

```
digitsum <- function(x) {
  r <- x %% 10L
  for(i in seq_len(floor(log10(max(x))))) {
    x <- x %/% 10L
    r <- r + x %% 10L
  }
  r
}
digitsum(c(1, 11, 1232, 4221, 2))
#[1] 1 2 8 9 2
```

Using RCPP might help to increase the speed.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
Rcpp::IntegerVector sod(const Rcpp::IntegerVector& x) { //sum of digits
  IntegerVector r(no_init(x.size()));
  for(int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i) {
    int s = x[i];
    r[i] = s % 10;
    while(s > 9) {
      s /= 10;
      r[i] += s % 10;
    }
  }
  return r;
}")
sod(c(1, 11, 1232, 4221, 2))
#[1] 1 2 8 9 2
```

---

Benchmark (taken from @Maël)

```
set.seed(1)
s <- sample(1e5)
dsum <- function(n) ifelse(n < 10, n, (n %% 10) + dsum(floor(n / 10)))
sap <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),""),function(y){sum(as.numeric(y))})
digitsum <- function(x) {r <- x %% 10L;
  for(i in seq_len(floor(log10(max(x))))) {x <- x %/% 10L; r <- r + x %% 10L;}
  r}
Rcpp::cppFunction("Rcpp::IntegerVector sod(const Rcpp::IntegerVector& x) {
  IntegerVector r(no_init(x.size()));
  for(int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i) {int s = x[i]; r[i] = s % 10;
    while(s > 9) {s /= 10; r[i] += s % 10;}
  }
  return r; }")
tic <- function(v) unlist(lapply(as.character(v), function(x) sum(utf8ToInt(x) - 48)))
bench::mark(Maël = dsum(s), user2974951 = sap(s), Thomas = tic(s), GKi = digitsum(s), GKi2 = sod(s) )
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total…¹
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t>
#1 Maël         15.69ms  18.31ms     42.3    38.91MB     77.3    23    42   543ms
#2 user2974951 134.61ms 154.97ms      5.74    4.82MB     14.3     4    10   697ms
#3 Thomas      166.84ms 172.98ms      5.73    2.29MB     17.2     3     9   524ms
#4 GKi           3.01ms   3.11ms    219.       4.2MB     26.8   114    14   522ms
#5 GKi2        546.48µs 564.06µs   1616.    393.16KB     14.0   809     7   501ms
```

In this case the C++ version is the fastest and uses the lowest amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `utf8ToInt` like below

```
> v <- c(1, 11, 1232, 4221, 2)

> unlist(lapply(as.character(v), function(x) sum(utf8ToInt(x) - 48)))
[1] 1 2 8 9 2
```